# Trouble with AWAIT / ASYNC and WebApi with FOREACH

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have multiple `async` methods that return the same type from different OAuth based REST Api calls.

If I call one directly, I can get the data back:

```
//Call a specific provider
public async Task<List<Contacts>> Get()
{
    return await Providers.SpecificProvider.GetContacts();
}
```

However, if I try to loop through multiple accounts, the object is returning before the `AWAIT` finishes:

```
//Call all providers
public async Task<List<Contacts>> Get()
{
    return await Providers.GetContactsFromAllProviders();
}

public async Task<List<Contacts>> GetContactsFromAllProviders()
{
    var returnList = new List<Contacts>();
    //Providers inherits from List<>, so it can be enumerated to trigger
    //all objects in the collection
    foreach (var provider in Providers)
    {
        var con = await provider.GetContacts();
        returnList.Add(con);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

I'm new to `async` and am probably missing something simple

Comment: Different situation. He's already got a solution to a different kind of loop and he's looking for efficiency.

Comment: The `async` keyword in the first method is redundant. You can simply `return Providers.SpecificProvider.GetContacts();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have provided will call the web service for each provider one by one in a serial fashion. I do not see how your statement *the object is returning before the AWAIT finishes* can be true because inside the loop the call to `GetContacts` is awaited.

However, instead of calling the providers serially you can call them in parallel which in most cases should decrease the execution time:

```
var tasks = providers.Select(provider => provider.GetContacts());

// Tasks execute in parallel - wait for them all to complete.
var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// Combine the returned lists into a single list.
var returnList = result.SelectMany(contacts => contacts).ToList();
```

Comment: `returnList.Add` is getting called, but the returnList has already been returned before all the items are added to it.

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` would be more efficient, right?

Comment: @MattJohnson: Yes, you are right. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: @Wesley, what is returned is a task that, when completed, will have `returnList`.